# Write to and read from the Windows Command Prompt by Java

Tags: java, cmd, io

I need to make a simple Java program that writes it output to the cmd (the Command Prompt) window and reads user's input from there.
When I run the code from the IDE using the standard `System.out.println` it presents the output on the IDE (I use intelliJ) console view.
I guess this is a simple question and there are already answers for it here but I made several searches and did not find appropriate resolution.

Comment: You need to run the program from a Command Prompt window instead of the IntelliJ IDE

Comment: Can I open the cmd prompt from the Java program and use it or it's not the right way?

Comment: @Eliyahu you open the command prompt, then run the java command to run your application. The application's output will then show up in that command prompt.

Comment: OK. I do not have executable file. Should I prepare it each time I want to run the program from cmd or should I run it by //>java filename.java ?

Comment: javac filename for .java files and then run java filename on the class file it generates

Comment: It's totally fine to let the IDE generate an executable jar file for you.

Comment: Anything wrong with `Scanner`?

Comment: @FattySalami I tried with javac. It makes nothing.

Comment: You can get user inputs from `String[] args` from  `public static void main(String[] args)`. You can see  the output on console with `System.console().writer().println("message");`. 
In order to run the application on cmd, you have 2 options:
1) `javac MyJava.java`  then `java -cp . MyJava` 
2) using `java -jar myJava.jar` if you export your application as JAR

Comment: The first option did not work for me, but the second worked. Thank you!
(But it's not short... :(  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it. your program now will output to cmd if you run it using cmd instead of IDE.
For input you can use scanner to read user input. or simply let user enter them all before running the program and include the args of main method in your logic to process user's input.

Comment: This is not an answer to my problem

Comment: @Eliyahu if you can read from and write to IDE's console, you can do the same for CMD. You do not have to modify anything

Answer (score 1):

demo for u :)

```
public class testCMD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testCMD obj = new testCMD();
        System.out.println("Press command here:");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String command = keyboard.next();
        //String command = "msconfig";
        String output = obj.executeCommand(command);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```